# Superkeys of this relation

Tags: sql, database, relation, candidate-key

I am trying to find the superkeys of this relation, but I am having troubles finding out how many superkeys there are and exactly what they are.  I figured out that the candidate keys were {A},{B},{C},{D}.

Here is the relation:

```
R(A,B,C,D)

Functional Dependencies: 

A->B
B->C
C->D
D->A

Candidate keys: {A},{B},{C},{D} (from what I figured out)
```

Can someone please help me find the superkeys, and how exactly to find them?

Comment: each of them can be a primary key and any combination of them is a superkey.

Answer (score 0):

Let me keep it simple:
Here is a definition for super key and candidate key:

**Super Key**

> Super key stands for superset of a key.
>
> A Super Key is a set of one or more attributes that are taken collectively and can identify all other attributes uniquely.

**Candidate Keys**

> Candidate Keys are super keys for which no proper subset is a super key. In other words candidate keys are minimal super keys.

Thus,any combination of candidate keys with other keys is a super key

In this example,
any combination of candidate keys of **A,B,C,D** is a **Super key**

Hope this helps!